# How do I intepret these t-SNE results?

Tags: interpretation, tsne

I am rather new to the TSNE method, and am learning about the various pitfalls associated with interpreting it correctly. I have performed TSNE on a very-high dimensional dataset (>20,000 dimensions) at varying perplexities as was suggested in [this article](https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/).

At this point, it is certain that there *are* different classes of these high-dimensional objects, but extracting them from data at present is like extracting milk from porridge, due to their similarity. One can currently make measurements that imply the probability that the object is a given class, but it is highly non-trivial to simulate and tag these classes.

At this point, I am merely observing this data to see whether or not any insight can be made into their underlying structure. I would like to know whether or not any conclusions may be drawn from this analysis and if there is any merit for pursuing them.

What I believe I know about TSNE is as follows (please feel free to correct me if I have misunderstood):

- **TSNE is probabilistic. I should not expect the same plot twice, simply similar plots if the result is stable.**
- **Perplexity is defined as 2^H(Pi), or the information associated with the surprisal of a given data point in the high-dimensional space.** This tells me the width of the t-distribution over nearest neighbours which I look at (i.e. P goes up, I measure more global characteristics). **It is wise to examine multiple perplexities and subsets of your data, to see if clustering remains stable.**
- The dimensions themselves have little meaning with respect to distances and variances. **If two clusters are far away from each other in one plot, it does not mean they are far away in 'variable space'.**

With this in mind, I have performed the following analysis:
PCA Reduction -> TSNE with perplexities 5, 30 and 50, for 300 iterations and two independent subsets containing 1/3 each of my total data.

The results are shown below.

Could someone please help a noob interpret these results? Are there any meaningful observations to be made from the clustering in these images? It will help my understanding for future endeavours!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT: Additional TSNEs performed without PCA.

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT 2: Additional TSNEs performed with 100 PCs and 15000 PCs

100 PCs:

[image]
[image]
[image]

15000 PCs:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe you are seeing PCA problems resurface here. On certain problematic data, PCA creates a topical "cone" type of projection that is not particularly helpful. Running tSNE on that probably doesn't help - PCA already mixed everything into a weird cone shaped blob.

Comment: Maybe add a plot of the first two PCA components, and try without PCA. Try to improve similarity *before* running either of them.

Comment: Sadly the first two PCA components only contain around 0.3% of the variance in data! One requires, at minimum 10,000 dimensions to describe 95% of the variance. I shall run the TSNE on the whole dataset and see what happens though.

Comment: The problem is that tSNE also uses the distances, and in such conditions, all distances are very similar. I remember seeing a variant for data with high intrinsic dimensionality, that may help a little bit, maybe. You should give it a try.

Comment: What you are seeing in the plots may be due to hubness, a well-known problem in high-dimensional data, related to the curse of dimensionality.

Comment: I should point out that the data does exhibit a physical cone shape. The fact that it looks like a cone is thus not surprising, I suppose. I have added the extra plots with no PCA applied.

Comment: What is the sample size here?

Comment: How many PCA components did you keep?

Comment: Why 300 iterations? What implementation do you use? What are other optimisation parameters? Left at default?

Comment: Sample Size: 10000 / 30000,  # Iteration: Default 300, have tried with 1000  - result converges after around 300 iterations, so little benefit of increasing according to implementation; 
Software Implementation: Scipy - TSNE
PCA: I kept all of them for this first attempt; I can reduce to around 15,000 dimensions to keep 95% of variance. All other parameters kept default.

Comment: Thanks. Note that doing PCA and keeping all PCs leaves all the pairwise distances unaffected (it simply rotates the data), so it should have zero effect on t-SNE.

Comment: Your figures look like some sort of convergence artifact (even though I know nothing about your data so maybe that is how they really look like). This might get better if you cut the number of PCs by a lot (even if you loose variance). Also, it's very odd to have convergence at 300 iterations given that the first 250 iterations are taken by early exaggeration. I don't trust scikit implementation very much, it used to have issues. Here is what I would do: (1) Keep ~100 PCs; (2) use https://github.com/KlugerLab/FIt-SNE (it has Python wrapper); (3) analyze all 30k samples together.

Comment: (Please include `@amoeba` in the comment text when you reply, then I will get your message automatically. Cheers.)

Comment: Maybe you want to try UMAP.

Comment: @amoeba on Edit 2 are TSNEs at 100 and 15000 PCs both.

Comment: @JackRolph Did you use scikit or fit-sne for this last series of experiments? In any case, the results with perplexity=30/50 and 100 PCs look reasonable, don't they? What you got with 15000 or all PCs are artifacts. I am not exactly sure what exactly causes them in this particular case.

Comment: @amoeba - thanks for all the help! my question is pertaining to 'what defines reasonable'? 'What conservative conclusions can I draw from this analysis, if any?' 'Can I determine from this analysis whether subsets of my dataset exist, and if so on what basis'?

Comment: For these general questions see https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/ that you seem to have read already. I thought your question was about why your tSNE results look "weird".

Comment: @amoeba Yes, I have read this, yet I still do not understand the conclusions one can draw from looking at one of these plots.  To be clear, I have a subclass of data. I want to know a) if this subclass is distinguishable and b) how distinguishable it is (i.e. is it a worthy use of my time to even bother with a machine learning technique to predict this subclass). The way it is thought of at the moment is that the classes sit on a spectrum: More Subclass A or More Subclass B, with a random probability of being either. Does this make a bit more sense? :)

Comment: Do you mean that your 30k samples are split into two subclasses, A and B? If so, why don't you simply color your tSNE plot with two colors and see how much they overlap?

Comment: If you have the class information for at least _some_ of the points, you can still color the scatter plot using three colours (A, B, unknown).

Comment: @amoeba It is nearly impossible to extract this information at present. Imagine that I am looking for the probable ingredients of a cake, where I only have baked cakes to look at provided randomly to me. My goal of this analysis was to try and see if the cakes clustered into subgroups, examine the distinguishability of these subgroups and thus argue whether or not it is a meaningful exercise to try and even attempt to classify them. It is likely there is a better statistical method out there to aim to achieve what I'm aiming at, but I can't tell whether my results are conclusive or not. –